# Command to check the amount of horizontal space

Tags: spacing, horizontal

Please, this is very important because I depend on it to finish my master's dissertation. So, I looked everywhere for an answer, but I could not find it..

Basically, I want to know if there is any command that print in the document how much horizontal space exist(pt, in, cm, etc) at the point where the command was issued. For example, in the next figure, i would like to know how long is the red line:

[image]
    Enter

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}       % Suporte a mesclagens em colunas
\usepackage{multirow}       % Suporte a mesclagens em linhas
\usepackage{float}          % Fixa tabelas e figuras no local exato
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{ragged2e}       % also allows hyphenation
\usepackage{booktabs}       % get "good" rules in tables
                            % Use it's \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule.
\usepackage{siunitx}        % Handle numerical value nicely,for aligning on 
                            % the decimal point
\usepackage{amsmath,environ}
\usepackage{blindtext}


 \usepackage[left=30mm,top=30mm,right=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}


\NewEnviron{variables}{%
where:\quad 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{%
        |>{${}}                         l   <{{}$}  @{${}:\enspace{}$}%
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}  X   <{}     %
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash{}(}   l   <{)}| %
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}  X   <{}
    }%
    \BODY 
\end{tabularx}  
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{variables}
1   & 1& 1\\
2   & yield stress\\
3   & plastic viscosity \\
4   & shear rate
\end{variables}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  The first thing I can think of is the `savepos` module of the `zref` package.  Read section 3,13 of the documentation of the `zref` package.

Comment: it looks like a numbered "equation". right?

Comment: By default text comes at the left margin so rather than adding the space and removing it it would be better not to add it.  But you have given no indication of how you added the space so it is hard to help

Comment: @GuM Once I saw a command that does that, but I'm unable to remember, it is very simply. I will check the zref package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In this case the ltablex package does that to the xtabular table showed. I hope to use the command in other issues as well

Comment: you haven't shown any use of `ltablex`  or `xtabular` please _always_ show a complete small input document that demonstrates the issue. It is really impossible to say anything at present, even if you knew that space was (say) 5cm it would not be possible to say how to remove it, `\hspace{-5cm}` might work, but if it is being centered that would be re-distributed so you would need twice that, or ...  but as I say the real answer is not to add unwanted space not to add space then compensate for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really recommend `ltablex` it has some slightly strange effects on tables, however it provides a command `\keepXColumns` which if you add anywhere in the preamble after `\usepackage{ltablex}` keeps `tabularx`  being closer to its original definition and produces the output:

[image]